# C-Style for loop works fine but changing to Swift for-in causes out of bounds errors

Tags: swift, loops, for-loop, for-in-loop

So I have this simple for loop that causing me major aggravation. See, it works just fine using a  C-Style for-loop (commented). But swift throws a warning (not an error) that C-Style loops are going to be depreciated in the future, so I figured I should change it.

When I try changing it, however, I get an `out of bounds` error which never happened with the C-Style loop. The error occurs at the `if` statement (so only if the mouse is over the cheese). And I don't see why it should work with a C loop and not a for-in loop.

```
func checkCheese(){
    //for(var i = 0; i < cheese.count; i += 1){
    for i in 0 ..< cheese.count {
        print(i) //prints just fine every time
        if CGRectIntersectsRect(mouse.node.frame, cheese[i].node.frame) {//throws the out of bounds error
            cheese[i].node.removeFromParent() 
            cheese.removeAtIndex(i) //the culprit?
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'd also like an explanation why the loops behave differently if possible. 
Thanks

Comment: Changed the loop, I was playing around with it before. Should be clearer now. Unless the problem is elsewhere. Where is there 0-1?

Comment: Nevermind. Please format the code so it's readable.

Comment: Using a C-style `for` -- or worse, *not* using one -- does not make this a question about C.

Comment: i suggest you name your "cheese" array to be plural, such as "cheeses". This makes it more obvious that it's an array, not a single element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cheese.count` is only being evaluated once. Suppose you start with 3 items in `cheese`. The loop will iterate over indices `0`, `1`, `2`. If you remove item `1`, then the old `2` becomes the new `1`, and there is no longer an item at index `2`. However, the loop will continue to index `2`, just as it was set out to do from the beginning.

To fix this, every time you remove, deincrement your index:

```
for i in 0 ..< cheeses.count {
    print(i) //prints just fine every time
    if CGRectIntersectsRect(mouse.node.frame, cheeses[i].node.frame) {//throws the out of bounds error
        cheeses[i].node.removeFromParent() 
        cheeses.removeAtIndex(i) //the culprit? ... no longer!
        i -= 1 //fixed!
    }
}
```

Now, that solves the error for the solution as you present it, but I propose a cleaner solution:

```
cheeses.filter{ cheese in
          if CGRectIntersectsRect(mouse.node.frame, cheese.node.frame {
              cheese.node.removeFromParent()
              return false //don't keep this cheese
          }
          else {
              return true //keep this cheese          
          }
      }
```

Comment: Ah ok, but it works differently in a C-Style loop?

Comment: I don't believe you can use your first solution as `i` is immutable within the loop – `filter` is indeed the better way of doing this kind of operation.

Comment: @ImmersionULTD No it doesn't, in C you would've needed `i--;`

Comment: But as stated in the question, it works just fine using the C-Style loop... Hmm i'm a little confused but thanks for the answer. I'll test it out and accept if it works

Comment: Because `cheese.count` was being reevaluated after every iteration, ensuring your `i` was always less than `cheese.count`. It would break if you used `cheese[i]` after the `cheese.removeAtIndex(i)` line.